# Problems creating a DynamicStream player with OSMF

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, osmf

I'm using OSMF Dev Guide to create some examples, like [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/OSMF/1.0/Dev/WSc6f922f643dd2e6d44125c0d12a34bbed7e-8000.html). But my player is doesn't working, I don't even received any error message.

There's my code: http://pastebin.com/EHySNRm0

I'm using data from a dynamic stream XML, generated by [BitsOnTheRun](http://www.longtailvideo.com/bits-on-the-run) (which I use in my extended FLVPlayback): http://pastebin.com/49GaQUR7

It's very strange because I use the very same data on my custom FLVPlayback and it works, using values from `<jwplayer:streamer>` and `<media:content>`.

I tried all possibilities for my video names, like: "mp4:name.mp4", "mp4:name" and "name.mp4".

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FLV's don't include the 'flv:' or the extension. See [FMS's URL format guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d117-7fc8.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d117-7fec)

Also see if this applies to you:
[flag for parsing stream name](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/net/StreamingURLResource.html#urlIncludesFMSApplicationInstance)

If you're hosting through cloudfront for example, this has to be set to true.

Comment: BTW, it worked when I setted _dynResource.urlIncludesFMSApplicationInstance = true;_. Is there any way to detect if my urls includes FMS instace name?

Comment: not that I know of. You'd have to write your own function to detect it. If you know the format of the stream name, you can try detecting where that starts, if it's right after host/app/stream-name then the flag should be false, if you detect that there's something in between like host/app/instance-name/stream-name then you should set flag to true